# Remover clase de elemento

Tags: javascript

Intento añadir una clase al elemento en el se ha hecho clic en multiplees elementos con el mismo nombre de la clase, pero al parecer todos los demás elementos activan al primero y no al suyo respectivamente. Hay un foreach en PHP, como resultado más de 20 de este tipo con la misma clase

```
Código HTML 
//Al hacer clic debe activar a site-options-dropdown
<div class='page-option show-options'>
    <div class='icon-src'>icono</div>
        <div class='site-options-dropdown'>
          opciones
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


Código JS
const cls = document.querySelectorAll('.show-options')
    Array.from(cls).forEach((element, i) => {
        element.addEventListener('click',() => {
            document.querySelector('.site-options-dropdown').classList.toggle('show')
        })
    })
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que tal, recuerda que es muy recomendable poner un ejemplo reproducible. En este caso sería recomendable ver la estructura básica en html en dónde se encuentran los elementos con las clases .show-options y .site-options-dropdown.

Comment: No entiendo bien la parte de *al parecer todos los demás elementos activan al primero y no al suyo respectivamente* ¿Podrías intentar explicarlo de otra manera?

Comment: @CarlosPozos He añadido imágenes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La razón por la que siempre se muestra el primero es porque estas usando `document.querySelector` el cual **devuelve el primer descendiente a partir de `document`**

### Solución

Deberías usar [`element.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector), el cual devolvera el primer descendiente a partir del `element`.

#### Ejemplo

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.show-options').forEach((element, i) => {
  element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    element.querySelector('.site-options-dropdown').classList.toggle('show')
  })
})
```

```css
.page-option {
  display: block;
}
.site-options-dropdown {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-option show-options">
  <div class="icon-src">icono 1</div>
  <div class="site-options-dropdown">
    opciones 1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="page-option show-options">
  <div class="icon-src">icono 2</div>
  <div class="site-options-dropdown">
    opciones 2
  </div>
</div>

<div class="page-option show-options">
  <div class="icon-src">icono 3</div>
  <div class="site-options-dropdown">
    opciones 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuesta entenderte, estoy adivinando que buscas esto:

```js
const cls = document.querySelectorAll(".show-options");

cls.forEach((element, i) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.querySelector("div.site-options-dropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  });
});
```

```css
.show {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='page-option show-options'>
    <div class='icon-src'>icono1</div>
    <div class='site-options-dropdown'>
        opciones1
    </div>
</div>
<div class='page-option show-options'>
    <div class='icon-src'>icono2</div>
    <div class='site-options-dropdown'>
        opciones2
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sí, algo así pero en lugar de añadirlo al icono solo quiero que se agregue a las opciones, intente con el document.querySelector('.site-options-dropdown').classList.toggle("show"); pero solo afecta al primero

Comment: Cuando des click en <div class='page-option show-options'> quieres que se agregue la clase "show" en <div class='site-options-dropdown'> que esté dentro de él?